# Flex 4.5 add multiple components to a container at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, children

I want to be able to add multiple children to a group.

I want to add all of this complete at once in "qItems"

```
 <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%">
  <s:Group width="100" height="100%">
   <s:TextInput width="100%" editable="false"/>
  </s:Group>
  <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
   <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
  </s:Group>
 </s:HGroup>
```

I can get pass only one child

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

protected function addNewGroup():void
{
 var hg:HGroup = new HGroup();
 hg.width=100 + "%";
 hg.height=100 + "%";

 qItems.addElement(hg);
}

  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button label="Add Item" click="addNewGroup()"/>
<s:VGroup id="qItems" width="100%" height="22"/>
```

I don't know how to add more than a single item at a time.

Thanks

UPDATE

I have this so far.... Looking for a better way

```
public var hg:HGroup;
        public var g1:Group;
        public var g2:Group;
        public var g3:Group;
        public var g4:Group;
        public var g5:Group;
        public var g6:Group;
        public var ti1:TextInput;
        public var ti2:TextInput;
        public var ti3:TextInput;
        public var ti4:TextInput;
        public var ti5:TextInput;
        public var ti6:TextInput;

        protected function addNewGroup():void
        {
            hg = new HGroup();
            hg.width=100 + "%";
            hg.height=22;

            g1 = new Group();
            g1.width=100;
            g1.height=100 + "%";
            ti1 = new TextInput();
            ti1.width=100 + "%";
            ti1.editable=false;

            g2 = new Group();
            g2.width=100 + "%";
            g2.height=100 + "%";
            ti2 = new TextInput();
            ti2.width=100 + "%";

            g3 = new Group();
            g3.width=100;
            g3.height=100 + "%";            
            ti3 = new TextInput();
            ti3.width=100 + "%";

            g4 = new Group();
            g4.width=100;
            g4.height=100 + "%";            
            ti4 = new TextInput();
            ti4.width=100 + "%";

            g5 = new Group();
            g5.width=100;
            g5.height=100 + "%";        
            ti5 = new TextInput();
            ti5.width=100 + "%";

            g6 = new Group();
            g6.width=100;
            g6.height=100 + "%";            
            ti6 = new TextInput();
            ti6.width=100 + "%";

            qItems.addElement(hg);
            hg.addElement(g1);
            g1.addElement(ti1);
            hg.addElement(g2);
            g2.addElement(ti2);
            hg.addElement(g3);
            g3.addElement(ti3);
            hg.addElement(g4);
            g4.addElement(ti4);
            hg.addElement(g5);
            g5.addElement(ti5);
            hg.addElement(g6);
            g6.addElement(ti6);
```

Comment: Robert, you should really consider accepting one of the answers to your question, for this question and the previous questions you have asked. This is how Stack Overflow works. Please read the [tour] and also see [ask] page for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The approach i have taken has been to add the objects an array collection then doing a for each loop through that collection and doing an add element to the parent container from the loop.

for example:

```
for each (var visualElement:Object in CollectionOfObjects){ 
    var newWrappingFormItem:WrappingFormItem = new WrappingFormItem();
    newWrappingFormItem.maxLabelWidth = 100;
    newWrappingFormItem.wrapLabel = true;    
    newWrappingFormItem.label = "Label Name";
    newWrappingFormItem.addElement(visualElement);
    parentContainer.addChild(newWrappingFormItem);
}
```

This example is using a wrapping form Item but you can use the same logic to create for other component elements.